# Xamarin Forms iOS App not working with Azure Mobile Services Active Directory Authentication

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-authentication

I have created a Xamarin Forms app that authenticates to an Azure Mobile Service using Azure Active Directory.  This works in my WinPhone app but it will not work on an iOS device. It works in the iOS Simulator, but not on the actual device.  I have narrowed it down to the exact line that causes the app to crash on the device.  It is in the AppDelegate.cs file and it is the "App.Init(this)" line.  It does not throw any errors (at least not that I can see).  It runs fine in the simulator, it deploys and installs fine on the device. However when you click on the app on the device to run it, it displays the splash screen and then just simply quits.

I followed the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users which is very involved and everything else works.

Can anyone shed some light on why the "App.Init(this)" would fail in the iOS AppDelegate.cs file?  It is implementing IAuthenticate (the full code is below)

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IAuthenticate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();

        //App.Init(this);  //If I uncomment this line, the app crashes. Leaving this line commented, the app doesn't every do the login/authentication.

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
    // Define a authenticated user.
    private MobileServiceUser user;

    public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {
        var success = false;
        var message = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            // Sign in with Facebook login using a server-managed flow.
            if (user == null)
            {

                user = await FormDataManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient
                    .LoginAsync(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController,
                    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    message = string.Format("You are now signed-in as {0}.", user.UserId);
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }

        // Display the success or failure message.
        UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView("Sign-in result", message, null, "OK", null);
        avAlert.Show();

        return success;
    }


}
```

Comment: Ok. I ended up following the TodoAzure example https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoAzure

I was not able to figure out why the Azure Docs example kept failing but when I moved the IAuthenticate out into its own interface and separated the platform specific code into separate classes for each platform (as per the TodoAzure example), everything now works.

Answer (score 0):

The azure docs separates out the interface into its own dependency service, but that doesn't look very clear.

Glad you got it sorted.  To provide another reference, check out the book at http://aka.ms/zumobook